# django-crispy Submit css_class

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using django-crispy to render forms for a project and I'm using bootstrap as the CSS framework. I have the following coding

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Fieldset(
            '',
            'username',
            'password',
        ),
        ButtonHolder(
            Submit('signin', 'Sign in', css_class='btn btn-default')
            )
        )
```

But in the HTML is rendered as

```
<div class="buttonHolder"><input type="submit" name="signin" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-default" id="submit-id-signin"/></div>
```

Note that the class is "btn btn-primary btn btn-default" when I want "btn btn-default"

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ButtonHolder(
        Submit('signin', 'Sign in'),
        css_class='btn btn-link'
    )
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation with your answer instead of just code.  I came across this question randomly and I honestly cannot see the difference between the code in the question and what you have posted.

Comment: This adds the bootstrap styling to the ButtonHolder rather than the button.